# why components doesn't render in parent layout with react router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using Frontend layout to render components.It render home page perfectly but doesn't render other components.

This is index file

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import { Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

import indexRoutes from "routes/index.jsx";

import { history } from './helper/history';
import store from "./redux/store/index";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={history} >
            <Switch>
              {indexRoutes.map((prop, key) => {
                return <Route exact={prop.exactPro}  path={prop.path} component={prop.component} key={key} />;
              })}
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

This is indexRoutes file for home page and login page.

```
import Login from "components/FrontEnd/Login";
import Frontend from  "layouts/Frontend/Frontend.jsx";

var indexRoutes = [
    { path: "/", name: "Frontend", component: Frontend , exactPro:true},
    { path: "/login", name: "FrontendLogin", component: Login , exactPro:false
];

export default indexRoutes;
```

In this file i defined routes

```
import Home from "components/FrontEnd/Home";
import HowItWorks from "components/FrontEnd/HowItWorks";
import AboutUs from "components/FrontEnd/AboutUs";

const FrontEndRoutes = [
  {
    path          : "/",
    name          : "Home",
    component     : Home,
    showMenu      : true
  },
  {
    path          : "/How_It_Works",
    name          : "How it works",
    component     : HowItWorks,
    showMenu      : true
  },
  {
    path          : "/About_Us",
    name          : "About Us",
    component     : AboutUs,
    showMenu      : true
  }
];

export default FrontEndRoutes;
```

In this file i render component in layout

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {  Switch, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

import Header from "components/FrontEnd/Header/Header";
import Footer from "components/FrontEnd/Footer/Footer";
import Menu from "components/FrontEnd/Menu/Menu";

import FrontEndRoutes from "routes/FrontEndRoutes.jsx";

import {  FrontEndAuthRoute } from 'helper/PrivateRouteFrontEnd';
import { history } from 'helper/history';

class Frontend extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {

    return (
      <div className="wrapper">

        <Header {...this.props} />
        <div id="main-panel" className="main-panel" ref="mainPanel">
          <Menu {...this.props} />

          <Switch>
            {
              FrontEndRoutes.map((prop, key) => {
                if (prop.redirect){
                  return <Redirect from={prop.path} to={prop.to} key={key} test="haha" />;
                }

                return (
                  <FrontEndAuthRoute  exact path={prop.path}  component={prop.component} key={key}  />
                );
              })
            }
          </Switch>
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default Frontend;
```

In this file i check should i redirect to home page or login page

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

export const FrontEndAuthRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={(props, matchProps) => (
        localStorage.getItem('music-director') 
        ? <Component {...props} {...matchProps} /> 
        : <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location } }} />
    )} />
)
```

please suggest me where i am doing something wrong

Comment: Please refer the duplicate post and you will get your answer. If you are still not able to work it out. Please leave a comment

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri no that is different scenario and have u seen i have already use exact property

Comment: Please read the answer carefully. The reason that your code doesn't work is because of the the exact property, reorder your indexRoutes and set exactPro to false. Once you do that, it will work

Comment: please see this link.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53706283/why-component-is-not-rendered-in-parent-layout-in-react-js-using-react-routing

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri ?